# How to concatenate text and numbers in excel vba and print out in a messagebox?

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

Let's suppose I have the following table

ID | First Name | Last Name | Overall revenue

3  | Blabla     | Blalba    | 150000

The task is to find the row with ID number 3 and print out in a messagebox "Blabla Blabla has generated 150000 revenue overall"

I am new to VBA. Can you please help me?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Use the `&` operator to concatenate strings, pass the concatenated string as the `MsgBox` function's first argument

Answer (score 0):

The cell values along with other strings in VBA could be concatenated using `&` operator.

For Example:
For printing 3rd row cell values in the provided format in message box use below subroutine:

```
Sub mbox()
    MsgBox Cells(4, 2) & " " & Cells(4, 3) & " has generated " & Cells(4, 4) & " revenue overall."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/replace-function)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Call message(3)
End Sub

Sub message(id As String)

    Const msg = "? has generated $ revenue overall."
    
    Dim rng As Range, s As String
    Set rng = Range("Table1[ID]").Find(id)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not locate " & id, vbExclamation
    Else
        s = Replace(msg, "?", rng.Offset(0, 1) & " " & rng.Offset(0, 2))
        s = Replace(s, "$", Format(rng.Offset(0, 3), "#,##0"))
        MsgBox s
    End If

End Sub
```